# accounting for differences in dependent variable measurement

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a data set in which intelligence was measured for 2/3 of the subjects using method 1 and for the remaining 1/3 with method 2. The dependent variable is intelligence score for all subjects, so I'd like to combine all subjects since I'm looking at how certain variables relate to intelligence in general, and I'm not interested in how intelligence was measured. However, I do want to account for the fact different methods were used for different subjects. So what is the best way to address this problem? Should I simply add a binary predictor that accounts for whether method 1 or method 2 was used to measure intelligence?
If my data set looked like:

```
    Subject  score   method  var1  var2
    1        0.4       1      A    122
    2        0.9       1      A    226
    3        0.1       2      A    724
                    ...
```

would this model be correct?

```
lm(score ~ var1*var2 + method, data=dat)
```

Comment: I think as you've written it, "method" will be interpreted as a continuous predictor, but you want it to be interpreted as a categorical variable. Try factor(method) in the model instead.

Comment: Thanks @rishi-k, yes `method` is a categorical variable that indicates if it was method 1 or 2. But does the model make sense like that? And is it reasonable to include a dependent variable which has been measured using different measurement methods?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it doesn't matter - you only have 2 values for it, so it's fine to treat it as continuous. I think it's the best you can do. Once you treat it as a categorical variable, you're assuming that method just has an additive or subtractive effect on score, which seems reasonable to me. Now, if one method has a higher variance than the other, that's going to be an issue.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't think about it... In the case of more than two values for the method variable, would you still recommend converting it to categorical? But what should I do if one method has indeed higher variance? That may well be the case in my data set...

Comment: Yeah, if there were more than two values, definitely convert to categorical. I'm just pointing out here, it'll look the same after conversion. Well, it depends how different the variances are, etc, and how many observations you have - and it also depends on what you're trying to estimate. I assume you're looking for a confidence interval and a p-value in the end?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @rishi-k, that's very helpful. Yes, in the end I'll be looking for p-values and confidence intervals. But what to do when methods have difference variances? Also would you simply add the term to the model like I did in my example, or would you have it interact with the other predictors of interest (score ~ var1*var2*method)?

Comment: Well, if the difference in variances isn't large, you can just continue as is. You'd have to check how bad it is.